# Trouble with rendering state in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having trouble rendering the array of key values from my state object. I'm fetching data (an array) from an API and mapping each element to an object which I set to menuData. However, I would also like to have a map that has the category names as the key and the value as an array of object items from that category. I set this to categories state variable in the line after
`setMenuData(itemsObject);`

However, when I pass `categories` as a prop to my MenuSection component, it doesn't render `{categories && Object.keys(categories)}`. What's even more strange is that when I try `console.log("Categories: ", categories);` it prints the correct object.

[Console logging categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO70D.png)

The weird thing is,
`{menuData && menuData.map(item => ( <ItemDetails item_name={item.item_name} price={item.price} description= {item.description} key={item.id}/>` renders perfectly fine, so I'm really confused as to what is going on.

Below is the code for my App and MenuSection component.

APP COMPONENT:

```
const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState(null); // list of item objects
const [categories, setCategories] = useState(null); // map of categories and items

function itemsToObject(data) {
    const menuList = data && data.map(item => (
      {
        id: item[0],
        item_name: item[1],
        price: item[2],
        category: item[3],
        description: item[4]
      }
    ));

    return menuList
  }

function categorize(data) {
    const categories = new Map();

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var item = data[i];
      var category = item.category;

      if(!categories.has(category)) {
        categories.set(category, [])
        categories.get(category).push(item);
      } else {
        categories.get(category).push(item)
      }
    }

    return categories;
  }

const fecthMenuItems = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/pho-hot');
    const data = await response.json();

    const newData = data.slice(1, data.length);
    const itemsObject = itemsToObject(newData);
    
    setMenuData(itemsObject);      
    setCategories(categorize(itemsObject));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fecthMenuItems();
  }, [])

return (

    <VStack bg='brand.900' fontStyle='DM Sans'>
      <HeroSection />
      <MenuSection menuData={menuData} categories={categories}/>
    </VStack>
    
  );
```

MenuSection COMPONENT:

```
return (
    <Container as='section' maxW={{base: '70vw'}}>
        
        <div>Testing: {categories && Object.keys(categories)}</div>
        
        <Heading color='brand.800'>OUR MENU</Heading>
        <CategoryNavbar />
        <Container>
          {menuData && menuData.map(item => (
            <ItemDetails item_name={item.item_name} price={item.price} description= {item.description} key={item.id}/>
          ))}
        </Container>
    </Container>
  )
```

Comment: could you please add codepen, for your issue, so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Look at this sample code

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('key1', 'value1');
myMap.set('key2', 'value2');

const keys = Object.keys(myMap);
console.log(keys);
```

it return san empty array `[]`

In your scenario try like this

```
const myMap = new Map();
myMap.set('key1', 'value1');
myMap.set('key2', 'value2');

const keys = Array.from(myMap.keys());
console.log(keys);
```

result `[ 'key1', 'key2' ]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah, I realized that I was using a Map() instead of javascript's object {}.